# execute function while importing in ecmascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

while normally importing module on older way we do it like

```
var a =  require('a')
```

also if we are exporting function from  'a' module we can do it like

```
var a =  require('a')();
```

but how can we do this in ecmascript
i tried

```
import a from 'a'()
```

but it didn't work
also if i did like

```
import a from 'a';
a =  a();
```

there is error like duplicate declaration
i am using babel transpiler preset of ecmascript2015

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with import syntax. The best you can do is to use different variable:

```
import aFactory from 'a';
let a = aFactory();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning the function & invoke it from the cloned one. Modules are prefixed to import & distribute, so I imagine cloning and invoking it from the clone would solve it.

```
import a from 'a';
let newVariable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( 'a' ));
```

try this, otherwise, try different methods cloning it and invoking it through the cloned object. Remember a = b is just a reference and it will result in the same error.